# Google Lighthouse: Using wrong image of SRCSET

Tags: image, responsive-design, responsive, lighthouse, srcset

I am using an image slider (owl carousel 2) and have implemented images as follows:

```
<img loading="lazy" itemprop="image" srcset="
image-320.jpg 320w,
image-480.jpg 480w, 
image-640.jpg 640w" 
sizes="(max-width: 680px) 320px, 480px" 
src="image-640.jpg"
width="480" height="720">
```

When running Lighthouse in Chrome Dev Tools for MOBILE view I get (among others) the following "complaint":

```
**Properly size images**
Serve images that are appropriately-sized to save cellular data and improve load time.
```

Thereby Lighthouse refers to **image-640.jpg**

However, as defined in my image tag the image-320.jpg should be the one taken into account. As for the SRC attribute I want to keep the image-640.jpg variant.

Is there anything wrong with the structure of my image tag?

Thanks a lot in advance and best wishes,
Alex